# rxjs expand, outer observable executing before inner observable finishes

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to get my `expand` operator to work, as I am not 100% sure of how it works, the issue that I am having, is that the `takeWhile` is running before the http request is even executed (on line `this.request<any>(result.body)`).

What would be causing this?

What it should be doing is increasing the offset everytime like so:

```
http://example.com?offset=0
http://example.com?offset=1
http://example.com?offset=2
```

Here is my function:

```js
  chunk<K extends Fields<this>>(size: number) {
    const table = this.builder.alias.length > 0 ? this.builder.alias : this.builder.table;

    return of({ body: {}, offset: 0 }).pipe(
      expand(params =>
        of(params).pipe(
          map(() => {
            this.builder.limit(size, params.offset);
            return { body: this.build(), offset: params.offset + size };
          }),
          concatMap(result => this.request<any>(result.body))
        )
      ),
      takeWhile(results => results[table].length > 0)
    );
  }
```

The error that is output is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Here is what the request method does:

```js
request(body) {
  /* create variables */
  return new Observable(sub => {
    fetch(url, { method: 'post', body: query, headers })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (logging === true) {
          if ('errors' in response) console.error(response['errors']);
        }

        if ('errors' in response) sub.error(response['errors']);
        else sub.next(response['data']);
        sub.complete();
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expand will emit the parameter before subscribing to the returned observable then it will recursively pass the emission of that observable in. It will still construct a final observable after the chain completes even though it isn't subscribed to.

```js
const { of, expand, take, delay } = rxjs;

of(0).pipe(
  expand(val => {
    if (val === 4) { 
      console.log('I am constructing an observable that wont be subscribed to');
    } else {
      console.log(`I am constructing an observable for ${val + 1}`);
    }
    return of(val + 1).pipe(delay(1000));
  }),
  take(5)
).subscribe(val => {
  if (val === 0) {
    console.log('I emit before constructing the observable');
  }
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Just put in a skip(1) in so that the initial emission doesn't hit the takeWhile

```
skip(1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit this so that the next `expand` doesn't execute the next time until the http request is done?

Comment: What do you mean until the http request is done? A http request is only made if the observable is subscribed to, the final observable is constructed but it wont make a http request as it is not subscribed to.

Comment: Each time the observable in the expand emits a value that will be passed back in on itself recursively, this is then emitted and another observable is constructed. If the observable chain has not completed then that observable will be subscribed to. There will always be a final observable constructed as the final value is emitted by the previous iteration. But is wont be used to make a http request once the outer observable is complete.

Comment: I just edited my answer to have a 1 second delay to show you the next iteration is when the constructed observable emits.

Comment: So, instead of a delay, could I put the http request there? The reason for this, is because I make a request based on the previous requests results. If the previous request returned `1+` results make another request with a new range, if no results were returned stop the recursion.

Comment: Just use the skip(1) to ignore the first emission

Comment: The `skip(1)` is what I was missing, thanks